# What state does a system collapse to after measuring a degenerate eigenvalue?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
Let $\hat A$ be some observable, and $\ket n$ and $\ket m$ two degenerate eigenstates with eigenvalue $a$, such that
$$\hat A \ket n=a\ket n,$$
$$\hat A \ket m=a\ket m,$$
$$\hat A(\sin\theta\ket n+\cos\theta\ket m)=a(\sin\theta\ket n+\cos\theta\ket m).$$

If $\hat A$ is measured with outcome $a$, what state will the system collapse to? Since there is a whole subspace that is degenerate, I suppose we cannot know precisely the final state (we do not have a CSCO). I suppose a density matrix is not suitable either. Is the fact that the final state will have the *form* $\sin\theta\ket n+\cos\theta\ket m$ the only thing we can say?

Edit: if the system is in a state that contains $\ket n$ and $\ket m$ as $\ket n +\ket m$ can we say that the system will collapse to $(\ket n +\ket m)/\sqrt2$?

Comment: If the system were in a state $| m \rangle$, what would it collapse to after the measurement?

Comment: @nwolijin I would say it would collapse to a general linear combination of $|n\rangle$ and $|m\rangle$. That is, we can only say it will be a state belonging to that subspace. That is what I am asking.

Comment: my initial guess would be that the system stays in the same state. Imagine that we have two observables, say energy and spin and that the basis in the Hilbert space is given by two states: $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow \rangle$ that are degenerate in energy. Now assume that initially the system is in $|\psi \rangle = \alpha_\uparrow |\uparrow\rangle + \alpha_\downarrow |\downarrow\rangle$, s.t. $|\alpha_\uparrow|^2+|\alpha_\downarrow|^2=1$.

Comment: Measuring the spin obviously result in the collapse of the wave function either into $|\uparrow\rangle$ or $|\downarrow \rangle$ with probabilities $|\alpha_\uparrow|^2$ and $|\alpha_\downarrow|^2$ correspondingly. Assuming measuring energy results in a collapse of the wave function to an arbitrary eigenstate of energy $|\psi' \rangle = \beta_\uparrow |\uparrow\rangle + \beta_\downarrow |\downarrow\rangle$, results in different probabilities  for measuring spin and energy, depending on the order.

Comment: @nwolijin I see your point. But when you make an energy measurement, you are perturbing your system, so I could see the system going to a different state. And in general, the order of your measurements matters (imagine the case of a spin dependent Hamiltonian), so I don't see why in this case the order should not matter.

Comment: @AsierR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels may help you.

Comment: @Asier R. spin dependent Hamiltonian is different from what we are discussing here. The two observables in question commute in our case

Comment: Knowing the observed eigenvalue $a$ s not enough to determine the collapsed state.  You also need to know the original state $\phi$.  The collapsed state is the projection of $\phi$ onto the subspace of eigenstates with eigenvalue $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of projective measurements, we just project the state.

So consider a measurement operator $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalues $\{a\}$. Let $\hat{P}_a$ be the projector onto the space spanned by the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $a$. In other words, if $|n_a\rangle$ are eigenvectors of $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalue $a$, then
$$ \hat{P}_a = \sum_{n} | n_a\rangle\langle n_a| $$
Now given some state that is in a superposition of degenerate states:
$$ |\psi \rangle = \sum_{n} c_{n} | n_a \rangle $$
After a projective measurement of $\hat{A}$, the system will be in the suitably normalized projected state $\hat{P}_a|\psi\rangle$. So it is in

$$ \hat{P}_a |\psi\rangle = \sum_n |n_a\rangle\langle n_a |\sum_{n'} c_{n'}|n'_a\rangle = \sum_{nn'}c_{n'}|n_a\rangle \underbrace{\langle n_a| n'_a\rangle}_{\delta_{nn'}} $$

$$ \hat{P}_a |\psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n | n_a\rangle $$
So the state does not change. This is expected since the state $|\psi\rangle$ is still simply an eigenvector of $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalue $a$.