# Does compatibility of observables imply a measurement of the second observable is unnecessary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurements, observables

If two operators $ A $ and $ B $ are compatible then their corresponding operators $ \hat{A} $ and $ \hat{B} $ share a common set of eigenfunctions. The eigenvalue-eigenfunction equation for each operator is:

$$ \hat{A} \phi_n = \alpha_n \phi_n $$

$$ \hat{B} \phi_n = \beta_n \phi_n $$

Let's say these operators are compatible (in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle sense),i.e.:
$$[\hat{A}, \hat{B}]=0$$

If I make a measurement on $ A $ and collapse it into the eigenfunction $ \phi_n $ then since the operators share a common set of eigenfunctions I know that the eigenvalue corresponding the observable $ B $ is $ \beta_n $. This seems to suggest that I do not need to measure $B$ independently to know the value of $B$ after having measured $A$. However the the momentum in the x direction ($p_x$) and the position ($y$) are compatible, but the idea that you can know the one from measuring the other is patently absurd. Where is the conceptual error?

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful here. Not every eigenvector of one operator must be an eigenvector for the other. Why is the joint measurement of $P_x$ and $Y$ "absurd", though? Note that in general it is "very hard" to associate a real experimental set up to a self-adjoint operator, and IMHO the momentum operator is such an example

Comment: So let me add: Measuring position in $y$-direction alone does not specify any eigenvalue of $P_x$  a priori; what you would have to implement (in the standard framework of QM using PVM) is a measurement corresponding to the basis $|p_x\rangle\otimes |y\rangle$. Again, how to experimentally implement this is another story. But the theory, yes, tells you that it is, in principle, allowed.

Comment: To illustrate: On the other hand, $X$ and $Y$ are also compatible, i.e. jointly measurable, perhaps this is easier to think about it. Now experimentally to implement this measurement is easy, just use a $2-D$ particle detector/screen. But if you would only measure the $X$ position, of course there would be, in general, not a definite $Y$ position. Likewise, measuring both $X$ and $Y$ jointly means that you did not measure $P_Y$. My language here is imprecise and so on, but I hope the point is clear(er) now.

Comment: How is 'compatible' defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you measure $A$ and it collapses to some eigenvalue $a$ that has degenerate eigenspace in $A$ but the eigenfunctions that span it don’t share eigenvalue in $B$, then what you are saying is invalid. Check [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618060/what-state-does-a-system-collapse-to-after-measuring-a-degenerate-eigenvalue) out. Explicitly, say that for some 2 dimensional space, $$A|\phi_1\rangle= a |\phi_1\rangle$$

$$A|\phi_2\rangle= a|\phi_2\rangle$$

$$B|\phi_1\rangle= c |\phi_1\rangle$$

$$B|\phi_2\rangle= d |\phi_2\rangle$$

And we can tell from here that $A$ and $B$ commute$^*$. However, if we measure $A$ and obtain $a$ we collapse into some combination of the $\phi$’s. This means we don’t know anything about $B$.

X-momentum and y-position commute. The y-position-basis is highly degenerate (in fact, it is infinitely degenerate), due to the tensor-product structure of the Hilbert space/observables. For each y-position state, there are infinitely many states that look like this $$|y\rangle\otimes|k_x\rangle$$
where I am keeping y fixed and changing $k_x$, and viceversa. Thus measuring $y$ doesn’t help us determine $k_x$.

*[For hermitian operators $A$ and $B$, they are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if they commute.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices)

Comment: Yes. The point is that the $y$-position-basis is highly degenerate (in fact, it is infinitely degenerate), due to the tensor-product structure of the Hilbert space/observables.

Comment: Adding thisthanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary counterexample. Consider an otherwise free particle in a rectangular box. The three components of the momentum commute and have eigenvalues are $p_x=\frac{\pi n_x}{L_x}$ and similar for $y$ and $z$. Knowledge of $n_x$ alone is not sufficient to characterize the particle state.

I have assumed that 'compatibility' is to mean 'mutually commuting'.